# Eclipse (ctrl+shift+f) does nothing

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

I made a new Java file in Gedit.

When I open it in Eclipse (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>), it does not format the code.

(<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) still formats other Java files (which I also did not create in Eclipse), and it even formats individual lines of code in this particular file when I press (enter) at the beginning of a line.

It just will not format the entire file with (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>). I restored defaults in:

`Window > Preferences > General > Keys`

But still nothing. I have installed no plugins.

***`Any idea why Eclipse isn't recognizing the file as something that should be formatted when I use`*** <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>***`?`***

Comment: Did you save the file with a ".java" extension from "gedit"?

Comment: Yes. Is that a problem?

Comment: Are you positive? Is it in your Java project?

Comment: I haven't actually been using Eclipse to manage the project. I've just been using it as a text editor. So far I've only been editing other people's files and everything has worked just fine. This is the first file I've actually created. It's definitely saved with the .java extension, it has the correct package and imports at the top, it's in the project folder, and it's a valid class.

Comment: Are you in the Java perspective? Given what you've described, it should work.

Comment: Yes, I'm in the Java perspective. I think it recognizes that, because it formats everything as expected for a single line if I press enter at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Are you sure the file is unformatted? Try select all (ctrl-a) then ctrl-shift-f.

Comment: I'm sure the document is unformatted. This is why I can say that pressing enter at the beginning of a line formats that line--because I see it fix the formatting. (ctrl + a) (ctrl + shift + f) doesn't work, but it turns out (ctrl + a) (ctrl + i) does.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why it wouldn't format the code with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> by try selecting the whole document with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) and then using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to format the document. You may have the same problem though.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this problem. And I figured out the reason by luck.

I am using IBus input method, and when IBus in Chinese mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> does not format Java source code in Eclipse Java project. When I changed IBus to English mode, that shortcut works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Check the followings:

1. The chosen active formatter profile is exactly what you want(You can find it in **Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter**)
2. The code lines which needs to format is selected correctly
3. **And the most important one** is **not to have any syntax error** in the file which is formatting

Answer (score 1):

Check for weird syntax in your file.  In my case, I had a method with an underscore parameter name:

```
@Deprecated
public synchronized void setParseMaxDigits(int _) {}
```

I had to delete sections of my file until I pinpointed that this was the function causing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to not format the file.  As soon as I changed the above method to,

```
@Deprecated
public synchronized void setParseMaxDigits(int unused) {}
```

then <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can only format a Java file when it is in a Java `Source Folder` of a `Java Project`. It won't do random ones you just Open from the File menu.

Comment: It is in a Java source folder. Eclipse formats the other Java files in this folder just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem just now.  The auto formatter seemed to not work for only a single file.  I even deleted and recreated the file but no luck. I eventually decided to keep working and all of a sudden it worked again.

The problem was I had a syntax error (a random comma laying around) that the auto formatter did not know how to format.  Fixing the syntax error allowed the auto formatter to do its thing again.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the solution that worked for me:

In **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys**, look for all commands using the Ctrl+Shift+F shortcut. To do so, click on the **Binding** column, so the commands will be sorted by shortcut, then scroll down the grid.

In my case, there was another command using this shortcut, that probably had higher priority than the format source command. So I just cleared the **Binding** field for it, and leave only the "Format" commands using Ctrl+Shift+F.

Answer (score 0):

**This is an issue caused by the *Razer Cortex* application**. Its keybind for enabling/disabling its in-game FPS monitor is the same as Eclipse's keybind for formatting a highlighted block of code (Ctrl + Shift + F). This program takes precedence over Eclipse in that regard.

Circumventing this issue is extremely simple:

1. Open the **Razer Cortex** application
2. *Change* or *disable* the keybind for showing/hiding the **FPS Display**

Your formatting keybind will work in Eclipse now :)

Answer (score 0):

Lee Duhem's answer let me realize where the issue is.The key `CTRL + SHIFT + F` may be conflicted by other apps,in my case,it's language input method.

System: Windows 10

1. Go to settings Language options
   [image]
2. Open Microsoft Pinyin Options
   [image]
3. Swift off or change another hot key
   [image]